# Interactive email form desconfigured in Gmail

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio, gmail

Im currently working in a NPS solution for my company, where we send a survey via email with a 10 star rating grid. In the interactive email studio, the email body looks ok, but when we receive it on gmail it render like radio buttons with a line to every grade (10 star line, then another line with 9 stars and goes on till 1 star). I found something very similar [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_interactive_email_display_faq.htm&type=5) but im not used to work with marketing cloud, there is any workaround for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is outlined in the help doc: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_interactive_email_display_faq.htm&type=5

> Why do some of my form fields look different in Gmail?
>
> The Image Single Choice, Image Multiple Choice, Button Single Choice, Button Multiple Choice, and Rating input types show a radio button or checkbox depending on their type in the Gmail web client or Gmail apps. Gmail doesn’t support some CSS attributes that we use to build the interactive elements while hiding the radio button or checkbox. While the styling is different, we’re not aware of any impact on usability or performance. If the addition of the radio button or checkbox isn’t acceptable for your use case, consider using these input types:
>
> Select dropdown or radio button for single option selection inputs
> Checkbox for multiple option selection inputs